# Print multiple pdf files in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32

My process to achieve, is to print multiple pdf files from a folder, closing Adobe Acrobat afterwards and lastly mapping the files to new folders, using another of my scripts.

The Mapping works as intended, but I´m struggling with printing all files. I can either print only one, or none of the files and Adobe still remains open. I've been playing around with asyncio, but I dont know if it gets the job done.

The code is not very well documented or of outstanding quality, it just has to get the task done and willl be very likely never be touched agein. Here it is:

```py
import os
import sys

import keyboard
import asyncio
import psutil
from win32 import win32api, win32print

import map_files
import utility


def prepareFilesToPrint(folder):
    # Scans folder for files with naming convention and puts them in a seperate array to print
    filesToPrint = []

    for file in os.listdir(folder.value):
        if utility.checkFileName(file):
            filesToPrint.append(file)

    return filesToPrint


def preparePrinter():
    # Opens the printer and defines attributes such as duplex mode
    name = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()
    printdefaults = {"DesiredAccess": win32print.PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS}
    handle = win32print.OpenPrinter(name, printdefaults)
    attributes = win32print.GetPrinter(handle, 2)
    attributes['pDevMode'].Duplex = 2  # Lange Seite spiegeln
    win32print.SetPrinter(handle, 2, attributes, 0)

    return handle


async def printFiles(filesToPrint):
    for file in filesToPrint:
        await win32api.ShellExecute(
            0, "print", file, '"%s"' % win32print.GetDefaultPrinter(), ".", 0)


def cleanup(handle):
    # Closes Adobe after printing ALL files (!working)
    win32print.ClosePrinter(handle)
    for p in psutil.process_iter():
        if 'AcroRd' in str(p):
            p.kill()


async def printTaskFiles():
    # Iterates over files in downloads folder and prints them if they are task sheets (!working)
    os.chdir("C:/Users/Gebker/Downloads/")
    filesToPrint = prepareFilesToPrint(utility.Folder.DOWNLOADS)

    if filesToPrint.__len__() == 0:
        print("No Files to print. Exiting...")
        sys.exit()

    print("=============================================================")
    print("The following files will be printed:")
    for file in filesToPrint:
        print(file)
    print("=============================================================")

    input("Press ENTER to print. Exit with ESC")
    while True:
        try:
            if keyboard.is_pressed('ENTER'):
                print("ENTER pressed. Printing...")
                handle = preparePrinter()
                await printFiles(filesToPrint)
                cleanup(handle)
                print("Done printing. Mapping files now...")
                # map_files.scanFolders()
                break
            elif keyboard.is_pressed('ESC'):
                print("ESC pressed. Exiting...")
                sys.exit()
        except:
            break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(printTaskFiles())
```

Comment: Try threading to create multiple instances at once